# bootstrap datetime picker formatting dates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, date, twitter, formatting, datetimepicker

I am using datetime picker for bootstrap. (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
I can not find any useful documentation about formatting dates

I would like a date format such as: Jan 2014

Any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see the example right in the documentation after searching "format" however just need to change format they provide to the example below.

Example for your case:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" data-date-format="mm yyyy"/>
```